# Isolated points of a recursive sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I don't know if this proposition is true or not.

Let be $f: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ a continuous function and $a_0\in \mathbb{R}$.
Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence defined by
\begin{equation}
a_n = f^n(a_0),
\end{equation}
that is the composition of $f$ function n times (where $f^0(a)=a$.

The question is if all points of the set
\begin{equation}
\{a_n:\ n=0,1,2,3,...\}
\end{equation}
are isolated points.

Comment: Please share your efforts.

Comment: I have tried various counterexamples but I think the question is not so simple.

Comment: I'm sorry that the post has been closed. I think someone could offer other interesting counterexamples. What can I do to reopen the post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint (that works): consider $f(x)=x^2-2$. It is semi-conjugated to the doubling map $t \mapsto 2t$ on $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ via $\phi(t)=2\cos(2\pi t)$. There are $t \in \mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ with dense orbit for the doubling map: take a number $t \in (0,1)$ whose binary expansion contains all finite sequences of zeroes and ones. Then the orbit of $\phi(t)$ is dense in $[-2,2]$.

If you wonder how to construct such a $t$, you can pick it via its binary expansion, that you construct by concatenating all finite sequences : 
$0 \, 1 \, 00\, 01 \ldots$

Comment: I thinked that there was a counterexample. This is smart. Thank you.